# Dropbox-Client does not work

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, dropbox

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit) and can't get the Dropbox-Client to work. I can install it but I don't get to the point where I should be asked for my user information (mail adress/password).

What I already tried:

- Installing the package **nautilus-dropbox**
- Installing the package from https://www.dropbox.com/install
- Download from https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86 an run with `dropbox start`
- Removing the folders **.dropbox** and **dropbox-dist** between the different approaches

Sometimes a window pops up, telling me that there was a 'Connection Error' with Dropbox and I should check my settings.

[image]

I do not use a proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dropbox working well on multiple 12.10 (32 bit) computers.  Are you using 64 bit?

I would suggest removing the nautilus extension and deleting all traces of dropbox in your home directory (such as the .dropbox hidden folder).

I then use ubuntu-tweak to install a new version of dropbox.  When it installs I got a message about it being in the wrong location, but it's worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I did what you suggested and installed dropbox thru ubuntu-tweak (which is same as installing the package from https://www.dropbox.com/install, actually) but for no avail.

I am using a 64bit system.

Comment: It works! Seems like it took the client a while but finally it asked me for my user credentials. My Data syncs now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Mine wasn't a very detailed or erudite answer, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to just post what worked for me.